# How to get previous URL using vaadin

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I have setup a web application with the sole purpose of redirecting it to my main web application. My question is how to get the URL of the redirecting application in my main web application?
I have tried request.getHeader("referer") but it just returns the current url.
The only code in my redirecting web application is response.redirect("main url")

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you should  create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.